# C++ Windows API цикл обработки сообщений

Tags: c++, winforms, winapi, c++-cli

Есть Windows API окно обернутое в клас. Создается в Windows API main методе например так:

```
Window* window = new Window();
```

В классе Window есть некий список Controls.
Цикл обработки сообщений сидит в конструкторе Window и тем самым не дает работать с window после его создания.

```
Window* window = new Window();
Panel* panel = new Panel(); // не работает
window->Controls-Add(panel); // не работает
```

Где хранить цикл обработки сообщений чтобы была возможность работать с обьектом после его создания?
Я знаю что можно вынести его из конструктора класса в main метод но соответственно нужно ещё и вытащить HWND из класса. Что если окна два? Хочется чтобы все обрабатывалось в классе.

Comment: Попахивает C++/CLI и WinForms, не?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov ага)

Comment: Цикл обработки сообщений никак не относится к окну, поэтому он не должен быть в конструкторе окна.

Comment: `Window` - это что? Из какого пространства имён этот класс? Из какой библиотеки? Судя по указателям `*` и `new` - это должен быть нативный (неуправляемый код). Но в комментариях вы добавили, что это winforms. `Panel` - контрол WinForms? Судя по конструкции `Controls-Add` - объект `window` тоже относится к формам. Короче, хрень какая-то. PS: в c++/cli используются управляемые указатели `^` и ключевое слово `gcnew`.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov по видимому, это собственный класс автора. Иначе как бы он поместил в его конструктор цикл обработки сообщений.

Comment: Используя WinForms, разработчики, по большей мере, избавлены от ручного написания кода в цикле обработки сообщений. Грамотно используйте события (events) и свойства контролов - сообщения от них будут автоматически переданы в тот самый цикл. Но иногда встроенных возможностей не хватает, в таких случаях можно перегружать метод [WndProc](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.wndproc?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Comment: Минус за "не работает". Что это означает: по центру экрана появляется огромная мигающая красная надпись? Опишите конкретно, что происходит: код не комплируется; компилируется но не запускается; запускается, но падает во время работы; работает, но выдаёт неверный результат.

Answer (score 2):

Вопрос выдает полное непонимание как работает Windows программа... вам бы почитать Петцольда.

По теме: цикл сообщений нельзя размещать в конструкторе. Собственно, цикл сообщений это и есть Windows программа - все, что делает любая неконсольная программа Windows, это выполнение цикла сообщений. Выглядит она вариацией вот такого кода:

```
int WINAPI _tWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPTSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {
    // Initialize app and create main window
    InitApp();

    // Run message loop
    MSG msg;
    while(::GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {
        ::TranslateMessage(&msg);
        ::DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return msg.wParam;
}
```

*(код немного упрощен, поскольку не проверяет возврат по ошибке GetMessage. В данном конкретном случае ошибка крайне маловерятна, поскольку все аргументы гарантированно корректны).*

Обычно программист не пишет сам цикл сообщений, а пользуется каким-либо фреймворком - MFC, wxWidgets, Qt, и т.п.

Не могу ничего сказать насчет фреймворка для Managed C++/CLI (по моему мнению, Managed C++ относится к C++ примерно так же, как Javascript относится к Java), но насколько я помню, для C# главная программа выглядит примерно так:

```
  static class Program {
    static void Main() {
      Application.Run(new MainForm());
    }
  }
```